# When using constraints, why won't this interface stay the same across the multiple devices available in the storyboard area?

Tags: ios, uistoryboard, xcode8

After trying to create pins to the edges, tops, and bottoms of these buttons, the UI still becomes either stretched or not wide enough when selecting the different devices available from the storyboard in Xcode 8.  What can I be doing wrong or how do I correct this issue because Apple won't accept this app due to it not showing in iPhone resolution on the iPad even though this app is set to run on iPhone devices.

[image: iPhone 4s]

[image: iPhone 7]

[image: iPad]

Here is an image showing the current constraints:
[image]

Comment: The yellow lines specifies that frame/constraint of your UI objects are not correct and has some ambiguity. Could you please show the constraints you have applied and also the correct expected UI.

Comment: How do I correct this ambiguity across all devices like the first image at the top of this question?  I'll add a screenshot showing the current constraints added. @Sharpkits

Comment: You constraints does not seems correct. Please check the answer for the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the demo project where you can find the correct constraints as per your requirement.

http://wikisend.com/download/172838/DemoAutolayout.zip